# Markov Chains expected number of steps

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I know that, if all the states are transient, we can get the expected number of steps between state i and state j by simply transforming state j into an absorbing state and do the standard process, where you go find the inverse of a certain matrix and add all the elements of the relevant line.

In the described algorithm you can tell the expected number of steps until  the process, starting at the state i, is absorbed.

And so my question is, how can you do this when the original markov chain already has absorbing states besides the state j? How can you know which of the states ends up absorbing the process and thus determine the expected number of steps between state i and state j?

Comment: The standard computation gives you the expected number of steps until absorption by _any_ absorbing state. If you want to look at absorption by a specific state, you need to condition the process on that.

Comment: @amd yes, that's what I was thinking... but any idea on how to go about doing it?

Comment: There’s probably some clever method that I don’t know about, but a straightforward, though tedious, approach is to delete the other absorbing states (and any “orphan” states that result), rescale transition probabilities and work with this reduced system.